# What is the .exe file that VS generates via .NET Core self-contained deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

[I'm using Windows conventions for convenience but this is an x-platform question.]

When I publish a .NET Core project (named, say, `Tannery`) via SCD, Visual Studio generates the application file `publish\Tannery.exe`, which is my entry point into `publish\Tannery.dll`. In addition, from what I've tested, `publish\Tannery.exe` automagically works with *any* config/build of `Tannery.dll` [on the target runtime].

This suggests `Tannery.exe` is just a thin wrapper around `dotnet.exe` and tantamount to `dotnet Tannery.dll`. However, I can't find documentation on this. So, what "is" this application file, and how flexibly can one use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use SCD you build your project for a specific runtime (e.g. windows x64), the build would include all the `dotnet` dependencies, so when you run your SCD on a system without the `dotnet` SDK, it will run without problem.

You can think about it as a wrapper around `dotnet.exe`, where the `dotnet.exe` is part of the build and not a system dependency.